# discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Converting to "ABCMeta" failed for parameter "member" await remove_friend error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def unfriend(ctx, member = discord.Member):
    await remove_friend(friend=member)
    await ctx.send(f'{friend} has been unfriended :<')
```

I'm trying to create an unfriend and send friend request command but this annoying error keeps showing up.

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Converting to "ABCMeta" failed for parameter "member".
```

Am I doing something wrong? If yes, how do I fix it. Please provide a clear explanation and a good solution, thank you :>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, as of right now, you are giving a parameter of `member` to be passed with your command. However, the `=` sign is to denote a default. So you are defaulting it to an instance of a `Member` object, I assume you are trying to use `type hints` which are denoted with the use of `:`.

```py
@client.command()
async def unfriend(ctx, member: discord.Member):
```

Then, you are attempting to use the remove_friend attribute, without using the object necessary. Which is either `User` or `Member`.

```py
await member.remove_friend()
```

The `friend=member` is not necessary here since we already referenced the member in the original object.

This is impossible to do with a bot account anyways as they are not able to add/remove friends. It will work with a Self-bot, however they are against TOS so I suggest against them.